# How to convert dictionary file with text and spans to pandas data frame using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list which contains dictionary and list elements. The structure is similar to this:

```
[{'text': 'convert json 1 to dataframe', 'spans': [{'start': 0, 'end': 8, 'label': 'person', 'value': 'person1'}, {'start': 46, 'end': 56, 'label': 'dob', 'value': 'bday'}, {'start': 61, 'end': 71, 'label': 'location', 'value': 'US1'}]}, 

{'text': 'convert json 2 to dataframe', 'spans': [{'start': 0, 'end': 8, 'label': 'person', 'value': 'person2'}, {'start': 10, 'end': 18, 'label': 'person', 'value': 'person3'}, {'start': 61, 'end': 71, 'label': 'location', 'value': 'US2'}]}, ]
```

It has `text` and `spans` and `spans` is a list containing entities and their `start`, `end`, `label`, `value`

How to convert it to Pandas Data frame in the below format:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `json_normalize`:

```
out=pd.json_normalize(d, record_path='spans', meta='text')
```

Output:

```
   start  end     label    value                         text
0      0    8    person  person1  convert json 1 to dataframe
1     46   56       dob     bday  convert json 1 to dataframe
2     61   71  location      US1  convert json 1 to dataframe
3      0    8    person  person2  convert json 2 to dataframe
4     10   18    person  person3  convert json 2 to dataframe
5     61   71  location      US2  convert json 2 to dataframe
```